# How can I play SWF files in fancybox 3?

Tags: javascript, flash, fancybox, gallery, lightbox

I want to use [Fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) for my portfolio, I have a mixed media: images, videos, and swf banners..
I want to use Fancybox 3 to show my works, but the only problem is that I can't play swf files, will very appreciate any help here.. I know this is possible...

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/ > Media Types > Inline or Iframe. You can put there any HTML content you want, including SWF object tags.

Comment: @Organis thank you for your reply, so I understand that I need to embed my swf into a separate html page and than insert it into my gallery as a inline/iframe content right? if so, heres another question, If I want to create a reuseable html page (1 single page) instead of creating many html files for each swf, that will load a different swf file by it's id for example into my gallery <a href... and how should I call this specific id from my iframe/inline... my knowledge in js is basic... thanks

Comment: I'd go for Iframe with PHP backend, so I could call urls like ...showswf.php?swf=file1.swf and PHP script would arrange HTML tags for me.

Comment: @Organis thanks.. my website is in html, I'm not sure if my server supports php.. it's a microsoft server (iis), I need to check... is it possible on html? please can you explain?

Comment: Well, you need to invest some time to level up your basic JS to intermediate or advanced. With JS you can **probably** obtain location.href which is an URL of Iframe, and then parse it for parameters and compose HTML tags you need to show SWF.

Comment: @Organis Thank you, actually i'm a designer, that's why my knowledgs in js is basic :-) I will try to research what you suggested and will update, appreciate your help..

Comment: @Organis, I used SWFObject to load a banner inline and pass it by it's id, works fine with chrome but not with firefox (it opens the overlay and a white blank box, but I don't see the banner), don't know about the other browsers, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Use JS window.alert(...) to debug things. At least figure, if things are going similarly in both browsers. Also, it's a good idea to use developer's panel (both Chrome and Fox have them) to look for any JS errors in console.

Comment: @Organis Problem solved! needed to add wmode:transparent, now it works on firefox too, very strange... anyway thank you so much for your help and your patience, I've learned a lot!

Comment: Weeeeell, I just kept pushing you to the general direction. Glad it worked out in the end.